# What does +1 Proficiency mean?

Tags: stardew-valley

When you level up Mining for example, the game will state that you get +1 in Mining proficiency. What does this actually do?

Does it decrease the amount of swings needed to smash rocks?

Or does this just mean that you leveled up 1 level?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Though it displays as a whole number, under the covers your character's stamina can have decimal values.  Levels in applicable skills reduce, by a fractional amount, how much stamina it takes to use the tool.  Here are the ones I was able to figure out.

These skills cause you to use **0.1 less stamina per skill level** with these tools:

**Foraging**

- Axe

**Fishing**

- Fishing Rod

**Farming**

- Hoe
- Sowing a seed
- Watering Can

**Mining**

- Pickaxe

**These always use 4 stamina**:

- Milk Pail
- Shears

(Source: I used a decompilation tool to peek at the source code.)

Comment: I trust in your reverse engineering

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about anything else, but higher Proficiency decreases the amount of energy usage for tools. I haven't upgrade my base Hoe at all but, without any hard numbers, I can say that I can till more spaces for the same amount of energy than when I started out.